# haskell repeat all chars in a string

Tags: loops, haskell, recursion, char

i just started with Haskell and wanted to do a little function that takes an integer and a String to repeat each char in the String as often as the integer implies.

e.g.: multiply 3 "hello" would output "hhheeelllooo"

My problem now is that i am not sure how to iterate over all the chars.

```
multiply::Int->String->String
multiply 1 s = s
multiply i s = multiply (i-1) (take 1 s ++ s)
```

so what i would get is "hhhello". so basically i need to do something like:

```
mult::Int->String->String
mult 0 s = []
mult 1 s = s
mult i s = "iterate over s, take each char and call a modified version of the multiply method that only takes chars above"
```

Thank you for helping me out

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: No, the first one was the homework, multiply the first letter - but i got this one and wanted to do something more. basically i just dont understand how to loop through.  My attempt was to remove each letter i visited from the list, as i would in java or c++ but i guess this wont work here

Comment: On a side note, we don't tend to iterate in Haskell; Functional programming lends itself to recursive solutions, such as mhwombat's, below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This gets easier when you use the standard library. First off, repeating an item is done with `replicate`:

```
Prelude> replicate 3 'h'
"hhh"
```

You can then [partially apply](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application) this function and `map` it over the string:

```
Prelude> map (replicate 3) "hello"
["hhh", "eee", "lll", "lll", "ooo"]
```

And finally `concat` that list of strings into one string:

```
Prelude> concat (map (replicate 3) "hello")
"hhheeellllllooo"
```

The composition of `concat` and `map` can be abbreviated as `concatMap` (this is a library function, not a language feature).

```
Prelude> concatMap (replicate 3) "hello"
"hhheeellllllooo"
```

So your function becomes

```
mult n s = concatMap (replicate n) s
```

For extra brevity, write this in [point-free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) as

```
mult = concatMap . replicate
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems like the easier way for me than doing what i had in mind

Comment: You can also just use `(>>=)` for the list monad (which is more or less `concatMap`): `"hello" >>= replicate 3`
yields `"hhheeellllllooo"`

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to achieve the same effect as you would with a loop in other languages, and larsmans has shown you one way, using `map`. Another common way is with recursion. You already know what to do with the first character, so you can recurse through the list like so:

```
multiply n [] = []
multiply n (x:xs) = replicate n x ++ multiply n xs
```

larsmans has explained how `replicate` works. For your homework, maybe you're not supposed to use library functions like `replicate`, so you can replace the call to `replicate` with your own version.

Answer (score 4):

Another way based on monadic's nature of list.
You'd like to apply a function to each element of a list.
To do this just *bind* the list to the function, like this

```
# "hello" >>= replicate 3
```

Or,

```
# let f = flip (>>=) . replicate
```

To remove flip,

```
# let g = (=<<) . replicate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use applicative functors for this:

```
import Control.Applicative

multiply n = (<* [1..n])

--- multiply 3 "hello" --> "hhheeellllllooo"
```